# Fixing an Index Error for a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, spyder

I'm trying to build a decision tree classifier, and I have the following code:

```
def dtree(data, attrs, target):

    data = data[:]
    vals = []

    for entry in data:
        entry_index = attrs.index(target)
        vals.append(entry[entry_index])

    major = majority(data, attrs, target)

    if not data or (len(attrs) - 1) <= 0:
        return major
    elif vals.count(vals[0]) == len(vals):
        return vals[0]
    else:
        pick = choose(data, attrs, target)
        tree = {pick:{}}

        for each in get_vals(data, attrs, pick):
            new_d = get_data(data, attrs, pick, each)
            newAttr = attrs[:]
            newAttr.remove(pick)
            subtree = dtree(new_d, newAttr, target)
            tree[pick][each] = subtree

    return tree
```

Where:

- `data` is a `pandas` dataframe of my training data `(33582 x 21)`,
- `attrs` is a list of the dataframe headers,
- `target` is the string name of the target attribute.
- `vals` is a list

When I call this method, I get the following error:

```
File "dtree_classifier.py", line 176, in dtree
   vals.append(entry[entry_index])

IndexError: string index out of range
```

I'm not sure what about that line is throwing the error and I don't know what I'm supposed to do to diagnose it.

Here's a data example:
[image]

Comment: Can you give us full definitions of `attrs` and `vals` methods. Also give data example, so your situation would be reproducible.

Comment: @GrigoriyMikhalkin I have, it's under the first code block. I have made it a little easier to read. An image of some of the data has been added too

Comment: I got it, `attrs` is a list, then what does that `entry_index = attrs(target)` mean? It's not valid syntax for python to call `list` data structure

Comment: Also, did you gave us full definition of `dtree` method? Because line `vals.append(entry[entry_index])` mentioned in error log is not present in there

Comment: @GrigoriyMikhalkin I have updated it with the rest of the method. For the record, the line you were not able to find was present in the original code block, its in the for-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, error occures in that part of your code:

```
for entry in data:
    entry_index = attrs.index(target)
    vals.append(entry[entry_index])
```

I guess, what you want to do here, is to iterate over all rows of `data` DataFrame and, from every row, add value of column `target` to list `vals`. Problem is occurring, because iterating over data returns column names(strings), not rows. So, when you indexing `entry` string, with index of `target` column, you get `IndexError`.

In pandas, there is much better way to get all values of column to list:

```
data[target].tolist()
```